# How to tag a product from an Instagram photo to an Ecommerce?

Tags: e-commerce, instagram, social-media

Please take a look on [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ginaG.png).

I want to do the same: tagging products that appear in my Instagram pics and link them to an Ecommerce website.
I tried to find Instagram tools to do that, but I can't seem to find them natively. Is that some premium feature, or how can I tag my products like that?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1108695469241257

Comment: @ryan Thank you!

Comment: "Enable shopping" is not appearing in my Instagram's setting menu. I believe I have the last version of the app, since I just downloaded it in my mobile. Any ideas why I can't see this option?

Answer (score 0):

This should answer as to why you can't see the feature. https://www.facebook.com/business/help/719199648241244. Also, if your E-Commerce website is WordPress, there may be a free plugin (not sure which one to recommend as there are several) that can take your WooCommerce and feed it to both Facebook and Google Merchant. Make sure you setup a Business Instagram from your personal instagram ideally using your mobile phone and create a business page on FB. Keep in mind you will only see metrics from Instagram AFTER you setup your business Insta acct. and not for previous posts already on Insta.

Comment: You should add some information, not just a link, so if the link breaks your answer is still useful.